# Redirect to current week

Tags: php, datetime

I have the url:

http://www.mysite.com/number/0

Here is:

```php
$date = new DateTime("2011-11-28"); 
$amountOfDays = ((int)$_GET['number']) * 7;
echo $date->modify('+'.$amountOfDays.' day');
```

Now I would like add an option, setting current date with monday. 
For example I have:

http://www.mysite.com/check

Here I would like to add:

```php
$datetime = new DateTime();
$number = ?;
header('Location: http://www.mysite.com/number/' . $number);
```

my site generate date:

```
http://www.mysite.com/number/0 = 2011-11-28 
http://www.mysite.com/number/1 = 2011-12-05 
http://www.mysite.com/number/2 = 2011-12-12 
http://www.mysite.com/number/3 = 2011-12-19
```

etc.

I would like in http://www.mysite.com/check checking current date and redirect to adequate http://www.mysite.com/number/x

for example if

```php
$datetime = new DateTime();
$datime == 2011-12-08; //should be redirect to http://www.mysite.com/number/1 
$datime == 2011-12-05; //should be redirect to http://www.mysite.com/number/1 
$datime == 2011-12-04; //should be redirect to http://www.mysite.com/number/0
$datime == 2011-12-18; //should be redirect to http://www.mysite.com/number/2
```

etc

There dates always are mondays (first day in week)

Comment: I see "you would like" a couple of things but I was rarely so unable to understand the actual question. So let me review: You have a script which gets a number from the user (`$_GET['number']`) representing the exact week, the user wants to see (or so). Then you "would like add an option, setting current date with monday" oO? What does "setting a date with another" mean? However... You would like to add the next code snipped - no problem but there is a parse error. Then (random) numbers/links equals dates.. which rule are they following? The rest I understood.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my approach based on my suggestions...

```php
$datetime = new DateTime();
$starttime = new DateTime( '2011-11-28' );
$daydifference = $starttime->diff( $datetime )->days;
$numberdifference = $daydifference - $daydifference % 7;
header( 'HTTP/1.1 307 Temporary Redirect' );
header( sprintf( 'Location: http://www.mysite.com/number/%s', $numberdifference ) );
```

PS: Not tested

Answer (score 0):

I think i understand what you want.

```
$ref = strtotime('2011-11-28');

$today = strtotime('2011-12-19');
/* Your selected Monday. */

$week = 3600 * 24 * 7; /* Number of seconds in a week. */

$number = ($today-$ref)/$week;
/* You could ceil() or floor() this, depending on how you want it to behave. */
```